# WordPress : Open all PDF link as iframe

Tags: pdf, wordpress

I have posts in my WordPress as a link for pdf like this:-

```
To show Doc place click here :-
http://domain.com/2012-04/item-1335086631.pdf
```

I need to convert this link to embed to show file in my site.

How can do that.

Comment: You can't actually unless to user of the website has a PDF viewer with a browser plugin. Not every user has that, instead the PDF will download on viewing the page. You really don't want that. Instead, you have to consider something like ISSUU to embed your PDF's.

Comment: There are [several](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/09/best-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin-examples/) javascript libraries you can use to display pdfs inline. [PDFjs from Mozilla](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) is one of them. Someone helpfully wrote a [Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pdfjs-viewer-shortcode/) to integrate it.

Comment: You could try [Google Doc Embedder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-document-embedder/faq/) you will need to convert the existing links in your posts to shortcodes.

Comment: I use WordPress , and have a lot of 100 post what can do ?